# Typing an array of objects as props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a functional component like

```
function ItemList({ items }: ItemProps[]) {
  return <p>items[0].name</p>
}
```

and I'm creating it like:

```
<ItemList items={items} />
```

`items` is an array of objects like `[{name: 'a' id:0}, {name: 'b' id:1}]`.

Everything is working, but in `ItemList.jsx` TypeScript is telling me `Property 'items' does not exist on type 'ItemProps[]'`

Comment: `items` _doesn't_ exist on `ItemProps[]`, because that's an array. It doesn't even exist on the things _in_ the array. Also the `props` argument is always an object, **not** an array. Did you mean `{ items: ItemProps[] }`?

Comment: can you show us what is the ItemProps type?

Comment: The props object can't be `Something[]`, because it is **always** an object, and never an array. Arrays can be passed within the props object. I think what you should do is `{ items }: { items: ItemProps[] }`.

Comment: You are destructuring. Without that, you'd write `function ItemList(props: { items: ItemProps[] })` *With* destructuring, you'll still need the `items:` key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function ItemList({ items }: ItemProps[]) {
```

This type doesn't mean that `items` is an array, it means the *props* object is an array. You need:

```
function ItemList({ items }: { items: ItemProps[] }) {
```